# how to add flows file of node-red while debugging custom node with node.js

Tags: node.js, node-red, nodemon

For debugging different scenarios I would like to add different flows to my node-red environment while trying to attach with an external debugger to nodejs remotely

I am using this procedure which is working, but flow file must be located in the directory of my node-red-contrib- folder

```
#!/bin/bash
nodemon --exec node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --inspect-brk  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js  -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*.* -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.html -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.js -V
```

Has anybody an idea how to bypass the flow.json file to the above command?

Comment: I think you are going to need to add some more context to your question. At the moment it currently isn't clear what you are asking. But you can pass the flow file on the node-red command line or pass a userDir or path to a `settings.js` which can be used to find the flow file.

Comment: yes I want to pass the flow file to the command above, but I am not executing the node-red command ==> I use pure "node" to start node-red. So how to pass there fhe flow.json?

Comment: `red.js` is the standard node-red command

Comment: And how to tell red.js which flow.json to use? I would like to bypass the Filename via cmd line

Comment: That is a nodemon question, "how you pass arguments to the target of the execute option"

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

The command from above is IMHO not correct.

After removing this I am able to bypass individual flows.json for any testing purpose:

```
-w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*.*
```

So the right command should be like (this is starting the default flows.json file):

```
#!/bin/bash
nodemon --exec node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --inspect-brk  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js  -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.html -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.js -V
```

For starting an individual flows.json file, just extend the command a bit (adding the path to flows.json file after red.js ):

```
nodemon --exec node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --inspect-brk  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js /home/dieter/.node-red/flows_tst_6.json -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.html -w /home/dieter/raspi_plc_workspace/node-red-dev/node-red-contrib-raspiPLC/*/*.js -V
```